# Elixir/Phoenix - Test pass when running file individually but fails when using mix test

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I’m having an issue where running an individual test file like so would pass:

`mix test test/app_web/controllers/page_controller_test.exs`

but running the entire test suite would fail:
`mix test`

```
 1) test GET / (AppWeb.PageControllerTest)
 test/app_web/controllers/page_controller_test.exs:4
 ** (RuntimeError) expected response with status 200, got: 302, with body:
 <html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000">redirected</a>.</body></html>
 code: assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Welcome to Phoenix!"
 stacktrace:
   (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:362: Phoenix.ConnTest.response/2
   (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:376: Phoenix.ConnTest.html_response/2
   test/app_web/controllers/page_controller_test.exs:6: (test)
```

I’m not too sure what’s going on but I have a Plug in my router that checks whether a specific cookie has been set for all incoming requests.

So I edited the default `setup` in `test/support/conn_case.ex` to add that cookie to the `conn`. Like so (my app requires no database).

```
setup do
  token = Support.Token.generate_token()

  conn =
    ConnTest.build_conn()
    |> ConnTest.put_req_cookie("session_token", token)
    |> Plug.Conn.fetch_cookies()

  {:ok, conn: conn}
end
```

Does anyone have any idea what’s going on?

Comment: When the test passes alone and fails within the whole test suite, it usually means some tests have side effects. Please note, that by default `ExUnit` runs tests asynchronously. You might start to diagnose with passing `async: false` option to `use ExUnit.Case, async: false`. Also, please share all your tests.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes you were right. I had tests where I was modifying the environment variables with `Application.set_env/3`.

Comment: Just do that in `setup` callback using the `context`.

Answer (score -1):

In your error log it says 302 . It means its re directing to other URI . Thats why its showing content of your html file. It's some thing wrong with your re directing.

Comment: Why it passes being run alone then?